# Calling a Function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have declared a function for showing a dialog box in jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showDialog(str,strtitle)
 {
if(!strtitle) strtitle='Error message';
$('#dialog').dialog('destroy');
$('#dialog').show();
$('#dialog').html(str);
$("#dialog").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    width: 400,
    color: '#BF5E04',
      open: function () {
                    $(this).parents(".ui-dialog:first").find(".ui-dialog
                                titlebar").addClass("ui-state-error");},

    buttons: {"Ok": function() { 
    $(this).dialog("close");    }},

    overlay: { opacity: 0.2, background: "cyan" },title:strtitle});}
   </script>
```

And I'm calling this function, in another javascript code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    var myFile = document.getElementById('myfile');
    //binds to onchange event of the input field
    myFile.addEventListener('change', function() {
    //this.files[0].size gets the size of your file.
     var  size = this.files[0].size;
     document.write(showDialog('size','File Size Exceeds')); 
      });
     </script>
```

When I execute the function, it writes Undefined, Why the dialog box is not showing. The first function is declred in the head, and the second in the body portion.

Comment: It's writing defined because the function showDialog isn't returning anything.  The document.write() is not necessary, just simply call showDialog().

Comment: have you tried running it through something like firebug? And stepping through, incidentally: on line 13 of your first section - is that line break there in the real code, or did you put it in to make it fit more neatly?

Comment: @Ivan is correct, just one addition: you might want to defer the call to `showDialog` until the page is loaded: `$(showDialog);` .

Comment: @Ivan how can i return a value from it, I am passing values to it, to show.

Comment: At the end of the function, just write `return "Some text";`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.write()` is writing what is returned by `showDialog()`.  Since that function isn't returning anything, it will write `Undefined`.

The document.write() is not necessary, just simply call showDialog().

Comment: Ok, but after adding the code , and what you said, it is doing nothing.

Comment: @Hanya Idrees: What do you mean "it is doing nothing."  That is saying very little. Is it throwing an error?

Comment: yea, dialog box is an jquery plugin i am using. And the same dialog box function works perfect on another page, called through a onclick event.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning any value in the showDialog() function.

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of `document.write()`, nothing is being returned by `showDialog()`, hence the undefined error.

```
<script type="text/javascript">  

  var myFile = document.getElementById('myfile');     
  //binds to onchange event of the input field     
  myFile.addEventListener('change', function() {     
  //this.files[0].size gets the size of your file.      
    var  size = this.files[0].size;      
    showDialog('size','File Size Exceeds');        
  });     

</script>
```